# Example of using a parameter in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

Very often, the files I am downloading have a date in the filename.

```
csat_surveys_2017_03_05.csv
03062017_roster.csv
```

My code deals with this individually.

- Compare the dates in the processed file list (based on slicing the filename) with the expected dates which should exist (some date range up until the current date)
- For each file I process, add the filename to a database table and only process new files which have not been added to that table

Can I (and should I) use the airflow schedule date to replace the need of having to code this logic? Every day, my task is scheduled to run. I take that scheduled date (minus 1 day, perhaps) and use that value as a parameter to pass as part of the filename to read (in pandas). If so, can I please see a clear example that I can use as a template?

Is that a better approach, and would that cover me if a file is missing or delayed for a few days (I would want the task to fail, then keep trying each day until it succeeds or until I notice it and can raise the issue to our clients)?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say yes, using the `execution_date` is probably best practice.

To access it, you'll need a templated field. Some default operators have those already, or you might want to create your own operator, which will then look something like this:

In your DAG, you'd have the task as:

```
my_task = MyOperator(
    task_id='t1',
    filename='prefix_{{ ds }}_suffix')
```

`ds` is the airflow macro for accessing the `execution_date` parameter as a string representation of a date.

And your `MyOperator` would look like:

```
class MyOperator(BaseOperator):
    template_fields = ('filename')

    def __init__(self, filename)
        self.filename = filename

    def execute(self, context):
        download_file(self.filename)
        do_other_stuff()
```

You can find more about how to parametrize tasks in the Macros section https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/code.html#macros